# AttachConsole in DllMain: console appears and disappears immediately again

Tags: visual-studio, dll, console, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to attach a console to a running c++ (console-less) program under Windows. As I have no access to the program's source code, only to the interface exposed for the purposes of writing plugins as DLLs, I do that in the DllMain of my plugin. The code looks like this (it is inspired by the [How can I attach a console to my win app?](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/how-to-attach-a-console-to-your-gui-app-in-c/) blogpost):

```
int __stdcall DllMain(void *,unsigned, void *){
      AllocConsole();
      AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());
      FILE* retStream;
      freopen_s(&retStream,"CONOUT$","w",stdout);
      if(!retStream) throw std::runtime_error("Stdout redirection failed.");
      freopen_s(&retStream,"CONOUT$","w",stderr);
      if(!retStream) throw std::runtime_error("Stderr redirection failed.");
      return 1;
  }
```

The window appears when the main program is instructed to load the DLL but disappears within a split second; the DLL is not unloaded as other functions from it get called. What can be the issue? How to keep the console open?

The main program GUI is written using Qt, but again, Qt headers are not part of the program's interface.

Comment: It is cringe-worthy code, there's a lot you cannot do in DllMain.  Definitely not throw an exception.  Definitely never ignore fdwReason.

Comment: Please read the DllMain documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: fair enough for exceptions; for fdwReason, I just followed the examples ofr writing the DLL for that particular code; so it is safe to assume it will be always that the dll is being loaded.

Comment: You must have seen a lot of really bad examples.

Comment: @HansPassant: perhaps bad examples in code costing 50k€ but that is another issue; not very helpful.